# Is the Talus (or Astralagus) the most frequently recorded fossil mammal bone?

Tags: paleontology, fossils

I was once told by a paleontologist that the talus (or astralagus) bone is one of the most frequently observed fossils among mammals.  Can anyone verify if this might be true?

Because of the density of the bone I frequently find talus bones as a walking safari guide in Kenya.  I could therefore understand if this bone is over represented in the fossil record.

I suppose also though that this is a difficult question to answer since there may not be any analysis of this kind within the scientific literature. At least, I have found none.

Here are below a few Talus bones I have found:

[image]